# Is it possible to have an (electrostatic) equipotential surface being crossed twice by an electric field line? If not, why?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

Lets say I have an elctric field produced by two point charges (not necessarely a dipole), intuitevely it seems to me that it is not possible to have an equipotential closed surface being crossed twice by the same line field and it seems also that it's not possible for that surface to contain, in its interior, both charges or none of them. Is this right? If so, how can we prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that there is a positive charge sitting on the equipotential.
There is an electric field line starting and finishing on the equipotential.
The positive charge starts to move along the electric field line in a direction opposite to the direction of the electric field. 
Work has to be done for the positive charge to move along the electric field line.
Eventually by travelling along that electric field line the positive charge gets back to the same equipotential and work has been done on it and this means that the positive charge has been raised in potential.
There is obviously a contradiction here and so the same field line cannot start and finish on the same equipotential.

Answer (score 0):

An electrostatic electric field cannot have closed loop electric field lines. This is, however, possible in time dependent electromagnetic fields. The electrostatic electric field corresponds to the gradient of the electrical potential , **E** = -grad . The existence of such a potential  is mathematically equivalent to the condition that the electric field is irrotational, rot **E** = 0, which by Stokes theorem means that no work is done on a charge moved along any closed path in the electrostatic field.